# Gerrit how to change notification sending email? (virtual host)

Tags: email, smtp, gerrit, mail-sender

Can I change the email address that gerrit uses to send notifications? And how?

I have consulted the documentation but I can only find how to change the *name* of the sender, not the sending adress...

---

My configuration and why this is a problem:

My gerrit service is located on an Ubuntu server called "devserver" and redirected by name-based virtual hosting in apache2 to the address "gerrit.mydomain.com". The issue I have is that the emails are sent from "root@devserver". Because of this, Outlook sends all the notifications to junk, and we can't unblock the sender because the adresse is invalid (most likely because it doesnt end with @domain.something).

I'm guessing "root" can be replaced by "gerrit" once I replace the account running gerrit which was "root" for test purposes, but how can I replace "devserver" by gerrit.mydomain.com? Is this a gerrit issue, an smtp issue, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following in the GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config file:

```
[user]
    name = Gerrit
    email = gerrit@YOUR-DOMAIN

[sendemail]
    from = SERVER
```

More info in the Gerrit documentation [here1](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#user.email) and [here2](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#sendemail).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!